# Dash exec redirection error

Tags: io-redirection, dash

This:

```
set -x
rm -f p; mkfifo p
exec 99<>p
```

succeeds in bash but fails (`"99 not found"`) in dash.

How do I get it to work in dash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The POSIX standard that was derived from the Bourne Shell and it's descendant ksh88 explicitly mentions that this is not granted to work. The reason is the shell syntax:

```
<>file
```

opens stdin for reading and writing, and:

```
[n]<>file
```

opens file descriptor `n` for reading and writing.

`n` in this case is a single digit.

You used the number 99 and this is a two digit number that is outside the range specified by POSIX. So the parser did not see it as a number that is related to the redirection operator but as a separate argument. So this argument was seen as the file to execute by `exec`.

If you like portable scripts, follow the POSIX standard and if you like to write fully portable scripts, make things 100% Bourne Shell compatible.

As there does not seem to be a reason for using 99 in your case, I recommend to use 9.

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? To open open file descriptor # for reading and writing is what I want to do. I can't have sepearate fd's for the FIFO or else it'll deadlock. It's perfectly possible to `fd = open("somefifo", O_RDRW);` in C without error.

Comment: ??? I recommended you to use fd 9 instead of 99. Why do you believe this will not work?

Comment: Interesting. The change from 99 to 9 makes all the difference. I thought the number didn't matter.

Comment: 99 is not a number in the permitted range 0..9

Comment: @PSkocik: POSIX specified that all implementation must support 0 to 9 file descriptor number, multiple digit number file descriptor left unspecified.

Comment: @schily Thanks. If you add that info into your answer, I will retract my downvote and change it into an upvote. (I'd do it anyway, just for the helpful comment, but SO won't allow me to unless the post is edited.)

Comment: It seems to be desirable for implementations to be required to create pink smoke in case of touching unspecified behavior. But we believe that this is a too hard restriction. Hey: creating pink smoke in this case is definitely permitted from the standard ;-)